# split sentences in each paragraph and wrap in span

Tags: php

I'm using this to split articles into individual sentences so I can highlight each sentence on mouseover:

```
$a_text = str_replace('<p>', '', $a_text);
$a_text = explode('</p>', $a_text); // Separate into paragraphs
foreach($a_text as $p) {
    $p_text = explode('. ', $p); // Only spilt on periods followed by a space to preserve URLs in the article.
    $highlight_text .= '<p>';
    $i = 1;
    foreach($p_text as $text) {
        $highlight_text .= '<span class="highlight" alt="'.$i.'">'.$text.'.</span> '; // Wrap each sentence in the highlight class
        $i++;
    }
    $highlight_text .= '</p>';
}
echo $highlight_text;
```

My problem is that at the end of every paragraph, there is a double period. It will look something like this:

> Sentence one. Sentence two. Sentence three. .

Nothing I do removes that trailing space + period from the end of every paragraph, and I can't figure out how it's getting applied.

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Answer (score 0):

The very last sentence in the paragraph probably has no space after the period, so it is retained and you are adding another one in the span.

Try trimming the last period in the paragraph by replacing:

```
$p_text = explode('. ', $p);
```

With:

```
$p_text = explode('. ', trim($p, '.'));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$highlight_text = trim($highlight_text, ' .');
echo $highlight_text;
```

Comment: I tried this with str_replace, too. Neither are having an affect.

Comment: Can it be that it has a trailing whitespace (which you can't see), so there is no match with : ' .'?? In this case, this will work: $highlight_text = trim(trim($highlight_text), ' .');

Comment: No effect. Maybe something with substring? But I've having trouble targeting it, with the trailing </p>